# Solution to nonlinear ODE using Contraction Mapping Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

I need to use the contraction mapping theorem to prove that a solution exists to the IVP $y' = \sin(x)\sin(y),\; y(1)=2$, on the interval $\;[1,1+h],\; h>0$.

My attempt at the solution. Let $E = C^1([1,1+h])$ ($h$ remains to be chosen). Let $\;d\;$ be the usual function space metric. Then $(E,d)$ forms a complete metric space.
Define the map $T:E\to E$ by the rule $(Ty)(x)=2+\int\limits_1^x \sin(s)\sin(y(s))ds$.
Let $y_1,y_2\in E$.

WTS: $d(Ty_1,Ty_2)\leq rd(y_1,y_2)$, with $0<r<1$.

By plugging in the expression for $\;d(Ty_1,Ty_2),\;$ I was able to perform a few algebraic manipulations to get to

$$d(Ty_1,Ty_2) \leq M\int\limits_1^{1+h}|\sin(y_1(s)-\sin(y_2(s))|,$$ 
where $M$ came from the fact that $\sin(x)$ is bounded. From here I got the expression:

$$d(Ty_1,Ty_2)\leq Mh\left(\sup_{x\epsilon[1,1+h]}|\sin(y_1(s)-\sin(y_2(s))|\right).$$

Here is where I got stuck. Usually, in the linear ODE and systems case, the absolute value is just $d(y_1,y_2)$, and then I can choose $h<\frac{1}{M}$ and be done, but here I have the functions composed inside of the sine? How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Please consider a better formatting for your question. Actually it is kinda hard to read.

Comment: I rewrote the post to be more readable

Comment: Thank you for your edit.

Answer (score 1):

For $a,b \in \mathbb R$ we have, by the mean value theorem:

$| \sin(b)-\sin(a)| \le |b-a|$.

Thus $| \sin(y_1(s))-\sin(y_2(s))| \le |y_1(s)-y_2(s)| \le d(y_1,y_2).$

Comment: Thank you so much!